# Stop processing nested elements and treat as string or raw

Tags: elasticsearch

Good afternoon,

Looking for a way to get elasticsearch to stop processing further fields and instead treat it as a string or raw. Keep in mind I am a newbie with the ELK stack. Basically I have something similar to the following:

```
{
  "_index" : "logstash-2016.04.21",
  "level1" : {
    "level2" : {
      "1" : "somevalue",
      "2" : "somevalue2"
    }
  }
}
```

What I would like to have happen is that the contents of level2 just be treated as a string and not create nested fields of 1 and 2. Hope this makes sense.

Thank you,
Mike

Comment: You can configure how fields are indexed in Elasticsearch by using mappings. Have a look here: http://www.pipebug.com/elasticsearch-logstash-kibana-4-mapping-4.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment @vipw. I'd like to find a solution inside of elasticsearch rather than using logstash.

Comment: I assumed configuring the logstash mapping is silently setting it up in elasticsearch. Is that not the case?
You can change mappings in elasticsearch directly:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the field in the template to enable : false did the trick. Thank you to @vipw